# Converting a JSON response to a TypeScript object using JsonConvert is working in all cases but one

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a couple of services that fetch data from my API, and converts it to TypeScript objects and returns them as a promise:

```
public getProductsFromApi(): Promise<Product[]> {
    const url: string = `${this.baseUrl}/products`;
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: this.credentials,
    })
        .catch(this.checkErrors)
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
            return jsonResponse.map((jsonProduct: string) => {
                const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
                return jsonConvert.deserializeObject(jsonProduct, Product);
            });
        });
}
```

For some reason, the functions never returns the array of products, and so the function that calls this one does not receive a promise...

My `checkErrors` function is like this:

```
public checkErrors(response: any) {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299) {
            const jsonResponse = response.json();
            return jsonResponse;
        } else {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
    }
```

I have tried using `deserializeArray`, I have tried doing a `forEach` and pushing the converted `Products` to an array and then returning the array, but nothing works.

Comment: what does the function return?

Comment: Nothing. I called my function and used `then` like this:

`getProducts().then((products) => console.log(products));`

and nothing is logged. I even put a breakpoint there and it never reaches

Comment: And you are sure the `fetch` is working correctly?

Comment: yes, `console.log` shows the values as expected. I even passed the json object without deserialising and my screen works. But then it beats the point of using TypeScript..

Comment: I added a catch, and it turns out the jsonConvert didn't return anything because my objects don't correspond: `Error: Fatal error in JsonConvert. Failed to map the JSON object to the class "Shop" because of a type error.`. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript) `jsonConvert.deserializeObject` is expecting an object as the first input, not a string.
Thus, you should first `JSON.parse()` the string.

```
jsonConvert.deserializeObject(JSON.parse(jsonProduct), Product)
```

Comment: I double checked, the `jsonProduct` is JSON, I wrote the wrong type in the code. It is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public getProductsFromApi(): Promise<Product[]> {
    const url: string = `${this.baseUrl}/products`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: this.credentials,
        })
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
            resolve(jsonResponse.data.map((jsonProduct: string) => {
                const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
                return jsonConvert.deserializeObject(jsonProduct, Product);
            }));
          })
        .catch(res => reject(this.checkErrors(res)));
    });
```

Comment: I am getting error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Response'.`

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox? And then i will help you :)

Comment: Also try jsonResponse.data as i'm doing on edited answer,  and if your issue does not fixed then provide me a codesandbox link to help you.

Comment: Hi, I added a catch, and it turns out the jsonConvert didn't return anything because my objects don't correspond:  `Error: Fatal error in JsonConvert. Failed to map the JSON object to the class "Shop" because of a type error.`. It was a stupid mistake.. Thank you for helping me!